# New Horizons MVIC/Ralph colour channel image alignment

Tags: imaging, new-horizons, pluto, image-processing

I'm working with some [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) MVIC/Ralph data. I'm taking the red, blue, and NIR channel data and create a false colour image, like this:
[image: Pluto+Charon]
([PDS Label of Red Channel image](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-p-mvic-3-pluto-v3.0/data/20150714_029916/mc0_0299162512_0x536_sci.lbl), accessed from [OPUS](https://opus.pds-rings.seti.org/#/instrument=New+Horizons+MVIC&mission=New+Horizons&planet=Pluto&time1=2015-07-13T00:00:00.000&time2=2015-07-17T00:00:00.000&qtype-time=any&unit-time=ymdhms))

Because of the nature of the [MVIC/Ralph instrument](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4281.pdf) (offset long, skinny CCDs in a time-delay integration scan) the individual channels need alignment. I manually aligned the above image but I am looking to automate/script this process.

Luckily, the angular offset of each channel is known:

[image: instrument FOVs]

([PDS Label](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-j-lorri-3-jupiter-v1.0/document/nh_fov.lbl))

I tried to use this information to calculate how many pixels to move each layer for [a different image (PDS Label)](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-p-mvic-3-pluto-v3.0/data/20150714_029917/mc0_0299178092_0x536_sci.lbl). The image is 5024 x 7776 px and [page 6 of Reuter et al.](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4281.pdf#page=6) gives the single pixel FOV as 19.77 µrad. This translates to ~50582 px/rad. Each channel is separated by 0.037° (19.77 µrad x 32 px) + 0.070° $\to$ 1.854 mrad. I expected this to mean having to move each channel by ~94 px (50582 px/rad x 1.854 mrad). This is short by about 10-12 px still:

[image: wrong offset]

When applied to subsequent channels (in multiples) the 10-12 px offset remains constant.

**What other factors could be at play here?** I don't think it's the [12 dead pixels](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-j-mvic-3-jupiter-v2.0/catalog/mvic.cat#:%7E:text=In%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20addition%20to%20the%20TDI%20arrays%2C%20MVIC%20has%20a%205024x128%20pixel%20frame%20transfer%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20array.%20%20For%20each%20of%20the%20arrays%2C%20the%2012%20pixels%20at%20either%20end%20of%20the%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rows%20are%20not%20opically%20active.) at the edge of each CCD as those are in the "other axis," but I could be wrong.

- Reuter et al. "Ralph: A Visible/Infrared Imager for the New Horizons Pluto/Kuiper Belt Mission," [Arxiv.org Link](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4281.pdf)

Comment: There is more than meets the eye here, alignment of top limb of Pluto still yields misalignment at bottom limb!